# File is not being made after I call my IO method

Tags: java, file, input, methods, io

`public abstract class TV implements Logger {

```
protected int currentChannel;
protected int currentVolume;
protected String model;


public TV(String model) 
{
    this.model = model;
    currentChannel = 2;
    currentVolume = 10;

}

public void incChannel() 
{
    getcurrentChannel();
    currentChannel = currentChannel + 1;
    writeToLogFile("Increasing channel to " + currentChannel);
    System.out.println("Increasing channel to " + currentChannel);


}

public void decChannel()
{
    getcurrentChannel();
    currentChannel = currentChannel - 1;
    writeToLogFile("Decreasing channel to " + currentChannel);
    System.out.println("Decreasing channel to " + currentChannel);

}

public void incVolume()
{
    getcurrentVolume();
    currentVolume = currentVolume + 1;
    writeToLogFile("Increasing volume to " + currentVolume);
    System.out.println("Increasing volume to " + currentVolume);

}

public void decVolume()
{
    getcurrentVolume();
    currentVolume = currentVolume - 1;
    writeToLogFile("Decreasing volume to " + currentVolume);
    System.out.println("Decreasing volume to " + currentVolume);

}

public void changeChannel(int currentChannel)
{
    this.currentChannel = currentChannel;
    writeToLogFile("Changing channel to  " + currentChannel);
    System.out.println("Changing channel to " + currentChannel);


}


public void writeToLogFile(String message) 
{
    model = getModel();

    try {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("./model.txt"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File("./model.txt"), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

        String line = br.readLine();  
        while (line != null) { 

            Scanner scanLine = new Scanner(line);
            String mess = scanLine.next();

            pw.println(message);
            pw.println(mess);
            line = br.readLine();


        } 

        br.close();
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();

    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("An IO error occurred.");
    }

}`
```

When I call run my program my writeToLogFile method is not working correctly. When its called it is not making the text file as needed. I need the writeToLogFile method to create the file and then append it when its called in other methods. 
Also, I have two models of TVs in this program. When I am using one of the TVs (Sony) I want it to write to its own log file named Sony.txt. I then have another TV (LG) that needs to have its own log file as well. Do I need to write two separate if statements to figure out the make of the tv then point it at its own log file?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a standard logging framework such as log4j?

Comment: I am new to file input and output and am starting with this framework.

Comment: I would guess there is a problem using a reader and a writer on the same file at the same time. I would recommend that you eliminate the reader and just open the file for append. Alternatively, you could open a different file for the writer, then once you're done writing to it, delete the original and rename your new file.

Comment: @BrewCrew15 I am not sure, but It seems that there is no "./model.txt" file, and as you first try to read an unexciting file Java throws FileNotFoundException

Comment: @BrewCrew15 Don't edit ypur question to remove the problem you're asking about. It just makes the whole thing a waste of space and time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with using the reader and writer on the same file at the same time. Once I got rid of the code where you open the file the method worked fine. I edited the code to reflect the proper changes.

I would guess there is a problem using a reader and a writer on the same file at the same time. I would recommend that you eliminate the reader and just open the file for append. Alternatively, you could open a different file for the writer, then once you're done writing to it, delete the original and rename your new file. – bcr666 6 mins ago